# VueJS Emiting events and passing data along the way

Tags: vue.js

Trying to figure out what to do with  passing around data with my parent and children components. Lets say inside the child-table component a button is clicked to open up the child-modal component. The table component needs to pass data to the modal so that it has data to process.

So I'm trying to figure out how to go from child-table to parent and having parent tell modal to open  with passing the data about the invoice.

```
<parent>
    <child-modal></child-modal>
    <child-table></child-table>
</parent
```

Table Component

```
created() {
        Bus.$on('invoiceEdited', (dataParam) => {
            this.onInvoiceEditted(dataParam);
        });
    },
    methods: {
        openEdit(index) {
            this.invoiceEdit = this.invoices.splice(index, 1)[0];
            this._beforeEditingCache = Object.assign({}, this.invoiceEdit);
            Bus.$emit('invoiceEditting', { invoice: this.invoiceEdit, phase: this.phase })
            this.$modal.show(this.editModalName);
        },
        onInvoiceEdited(dataParam) {
            this.invoices.push(dataParam.invoice);
            this.clearEditInvoice();
            this.$modal.hide(this.editModalName);
        },
```

Parent

```
    created() {
        Bus.$on('invoiceEditting', (dataParam) => {
            this.onInvoiceEdit(dataParam);
        });
    },
    methods: {
        onInvoiceEdit(dataParam) {
            this.editing = true;
            this.invoice = dataParam.invoice;
            this.phase = dataParam.phase;
        },
```

Comment: What does `this.editing` do? Hows the parent triggering the modal?

Answer (score 0):

For parent and child components, you can do it in an easier way.

The following is just a demo.

### Parent

```
<child-component v-on:increment="increaseCount"></child-component>
```

---

```
export default {
  name: 'parent-component',
  data () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increaseCount: () => this.count++
  }
}
```

### Child

```
<template>
  <button @click="incrementCount"></button>
</template>
```

---

```
export default {
  name: 'child-component',
  methods: {
    incrementCount: () => this.$emit('increment')
  }
}
```